# How to unwrap double optionals?

Tags: swift

How do you unwrap a string that is returned as:

> (Optional(Optional "blue"))

```
var cityName = String()

if let cityAnno = annotation as MGLAnnotation! {
    cityName = String(stringInterpolationSegment: cityAnno.title!)
}

cityLabelName.text = ("\(cityName), \(county)")
```

cityLabelName prints out as `(Optional "New York")`

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Given a double optional such as this doubly wrapped `String`:

```
let a: String?? = "hello"
print(a as Any) // "Optional(Optional("hello"))\n"
```

@Leo, [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049357/1630618) that you could use *optional binding* twice:

```
if let temp = a, let value = temp {
    print(value) // "hello\n"
}
```

or force unwrap twice:

```
print(value!!)  // don't do this - you're just asking for a crash
```

---

Here are 5 more methods you can use to safely unwrap a double optional:

**Method 1:**

You can also use *pattern matching*:

```
if case let value?? = a {
    print(value) // "hello\n"
}
```

As @netdigger noted in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445985/1630618), this can also be written as:

```
if case .some(.some(let value)) = a {
    print(value) // "hello\n"
}
```

which while less concise might be a bit easier to read.

---

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` twice:

```
print((a ?? "") ?? "")  // "hello\n"
```

**Note:** Unlike the other methods presented here, this will always produce a value.  `""` (empty `String`) is used if either of the optionals is `nil`.

---

**Method 3:**

Or you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` with *optional binding*:

```
if let value = a ?? nil {
    print(value)  // "hello\n"
}
```

**How does this work?**

With a doubly wrapped optional, the value held by the variable could be one of 3 things: `Optional(Optional("some string"))`, `Optional(nil)` if the inner optional is `nil`, or `nil` if the outer optional is `nil`. So a `?? nil` unwraps the outer optional. If the outer optional is `nil`, then `??` replaces it with the default value of `nil`. If `a` is `Optional(nil)`, then `??` will unwrap the outer optional leaving `nil`. At this point you will have a `String?` that is `nil` if either the inner or outer optional is `nil`. If there is a `String` inside, you get `Optional("some string")`.

Finally, the *optional binding* (`if let`) unwraps `Optional("some string")` to get `"some string"` or the *optional binding* fails if either of the optionals is `nil` and skips the block.

---

**Method 4:**

Also, you can use `flatMap` with *optional binding*:

```
if let value = a.flatMap({ $0 }) {
    print(value)  // "hello\n"
}
```

---

**Method 5:**

Conditionally cast the value to the type.  Surprisingly, this will remove all levels of optionals:

```
let a: String?? = "hello"
let b: String??????? = "bye"

if let value = a as? String {
    print(value)  // "hello\n"
}

print(b as Any)  // "Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional(Optional("bye")))))))\n"

if let value = b as? String {
    print(value)  // "bye\n"
}
```

Comment: The `?? nil` is brilliant!

Comment: This is the best answer, especially Method 3.

Comment: I like method 1 although the pattern matching syntax takes some getting used to. Why and how does method 3 work?

Comment: @Raginmari, with a doubly wrapped optional, the value held by the variable could be one of 3 things: `Optional(Optional("some string"))`, `Optional(nil)` if the inner optional is `nil`, or `nil` if the outer optional is `nil`.  So `a ?? nil` unwraps the outer optional.  If the outer optional is `nil`, then ?? replaces it with the default value of `nil`.  If `a` is `Optional(nil)`, then ?? will unwrap the outer optional leaving `nil`.  At this point, you get `nil` if either the inner or outer optional is `nil`.  If there is a string inside, you get `Optional("some string")`.

Comment: Finally, the optional binding unwraps `Optional("some string")` to get `"some string"` or it fails if either of the optionals was `nil`.

Comment: Method #1 has a really weird syntax! I've used it for enums but never like this. I also found Method #5 very interesting. Infact these 2 are the most concise and neat when it comes to a multi-optional variable but I highly doubt I will ever come across such a scenario :D

Comment: Methods 1 and 3 are the best code snippets I've read on the case. Thank you for such a great post!

Comment: I suggest a language update that would use `iff let value = a`. It would be a nice shortcut to unwrap both optionals.

Comment: I also note that these methods are not functionally equivalent. Some will execute the code producing a nil. Others will skip the code.

Comment: All if the `if let` methods above perform optional binding and will skip the block if either optional is `nil`.  Method 2 will produce `""` (empty String) if either optional is `nil`.  Force unwrapping twice will crash if either optional is `nil`.

Comment: I really like method 3. (voted) It took me a minute to realize that it's actaually intepreted as `if let value = (a ?? nil)`

Comment: Nice! I particularly like the conditional cast, since, like you said, it removes all levels of optionals!

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
var a:String?? = "1"
print((a))
if let b = a,c = b{
    print(c)
}
```

Screenshot of playground

[image]

Also you can force unwrap,but it it is not secure

```
let d = a!!
```

Answer (score 4):

I must say the accepted answer is very good, and I pefer `method 1` from from that answer. However I'd like to use different syntax, making it a little more readable:

```
if case .some(.some(let value)) = a {
    print(value) // "hello\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a `reduce()` method on `Optional` to transform an `Optional(Optional(U))` into an `Optional(U)` (like `flatten()` in Scala):

```
extension Optional {
    /// - Returns: Given an Optional(Optional(U)) returns an Optional(U)
    func reduce<U>() -> U? {
        switch self {
        case let unwrapped?:
            return unwrapped as? U
        default:
            return .none
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

String example:

```
// By using reduce() you directly got a standard optional you can unwrap in the standard way (see answer of @vacawama above).
let aString: String? = Optional(Optional("Hello")).reduce()

let unwrapped = aString ?? "Default"
```

Int example:

```
// By using reduce() you directly got a standard optional you can unwrap in the standard way (see answer of @vacawama above).
let anInt: Int? = Optional(Optional(5)).reduce()

let unwrapped = anInt ?? 10
```

I mainly use it when I want to call a method which can throw an exception but for which in the current context I don't want to catch it. An example is reading a user property in the keychain:

```
let username: String = (try? keychain.get("username")).reduce() ?? "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace cast to optional `if let cityAnno = annotation as MGLAnnotation!` with an optional cast `if let cityAnno = annotation as? MGLAnnotation`

If you ended up having a double optional type, you probably made a mistake before that.

For example:

1. Casted to optional type, e.g. `value as? Value?` instead of `value as? Value`
2. Used `map` and returned an optional instead of using `flatMap`
3. Created a `Dictionary` with optional values `[Key: Value?]` so subscript returns `Value??`
4. Created an array of optionals
5. Mapped an array using `map` instead of `compactMap` and then called a method that normally returns optional, e.g., `first` except now it's double optional

In 99% of cases, all of the above can be and should be avoided. In cases when you really need it, you probably already know all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.7, you can use

```
let value: String?? = "hello"
if let value, let value {
    print(value) // "hello"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<sub>This is more of an important comment.</sub>

Think of a double optional as such:

```
indirect enum S {
  case value(s: S?)
  case none
}
```

While a normal optional is like this:

```
enum S {
  case value(s: S)
  case none
}
```

<sub>understanding why [`indirect`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-indirect-enums) is used in the first example is unimportant to scope of the question asked. It just doesn't compile without it! In the first example I was just trying to show that its *internal* type is also an **optional** type</sub>