# iOS RxSwift - How to unwrap an `Optional<Optional<T>>` or `T??`?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swift4, rx-swift, rx-blocking

I'm using the logic below to check the state of my subject using RxBlocking. I'm getting a weird value of `Int??` out of `try? subject.verifier.toBlocking().first()`.

The syntax below pleases the compiler but makes my eyes bleed.

**How do I get an unwrapped value out of RXBlocking expectation?**

```
func checkSubjectState() -> Int
    {
      let updatedChecksum = try? subject.verifier.toBlocking().first() ?? 0
      return updatedChecksum ?? 0
    }

let expectedCheckSum = checkSubjectState()
expect(expectedCheckSum).to(equal(knownValue))
```

Comment: There you go, three different answers. Accept whichever you like best. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049246/how-to-unwrap-double-optionals

Comment: I want this question to be related to RxBlocking, as this syntax pops up in some examples and people may be confused as to how to deal with it. I think Quick/Nimble handles comparison between Int and Int? as expected, but problems arise as I use the result in print statements and such. I expect ?? 0 to produce a real zero Int, but it seems to produce an optional zero Int

Comment: I agree which is why I didn't recommend removing the question. I mentioned the relationship because there are several different ways to solve this problem as outlined on that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unwrap double optionals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049246/how-to-unwrap-double-optionals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that doesn't require you to define any of your own functions:

```
return (try? subject.verifier.toBlocking().first()).flatMap { $0 } ?? 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yea, so `first()` can throw *and* it returns an Optional type, so `try? first()` returns an `Optional<Optional<Int>>` or `Int??`. Frankly, I think the `first()` function is poorly written. It should either throw *or* return optional, not both.

You could write a `flattened` operator:

```
public protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var value: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    public var value: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped: OptionalType {
    var flattened: Wrapped.Wrapped? {
        switch self {
        case let .some(opt):
            return opt.value
        case .none:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
let expectedCheckSum = (try? subject.verifier.toBlocking().first()).flattened ?? 0
```

Whether you think it's worth it or not is your call.

Answer (score 2):

There are two other alternatives avoiding the double optional by handling the error

The first hands over the error to the caller

```
func checkSubjectState() throws -> Int
{
  return try subject.verifier.toBlocking().first() ?? 0
}
```

The second adds a `do - catch` block

```
func checkSubjectState() -> Int
{
    do { return try subject.verifier.toBlocking().first() ?? 0 } 
    catch { return 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another solution that I think you might like more:

```
infix operator ???: NilCoalescingPrecedence
func ???<T>(opt: T??, val: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {
    return ((opt ?? val()) ?? val())
}
```

The above will allow you to simply:

```
return (try? subject.verifier.toBlocking().first()) ??? 0
```

I tried to give the operator a higher precedence than the `try?` so the parens wouldn't be needed, but I couldn't find a way to do that.