# Swift 5 : if let for dictionary access does not unwrap value

Tags: swift

I have the following playground code :

```
typealias ChessItemPosition = (alpha:Character, num:Int)
typealias Chessman = Dictionary<String,ChessItemPosition?>

var chessmans : Chessman = [:]
chessmans["White king"] = (alpha : "e", num : 2)
chessmans["Black king"] = (alpha : "e", num : 6)
chessmans["Black queen"] = nil

var itemPosition = chessmans["Black queen"]

if let chessItemPosition = itemPosition {
    print("Current position is : \(chessItemPosition!.alpha)\(chessItemPosition!.num)")
} else {
    print("Black queen is dead")
}
```

Why do I need to use !. syntax to access the tuple content? When I have

```
var markCount : Int? = 8

if let markCount_ = markCount {
    print("\(markCount_)")
}
```

and no ! is required here. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unwrap double optionals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049246/how-to-unwrap-double-optionals)

Comment: @imike, thanks a lot for your hint - indeed I have a double optional in this case. I'll post an answer right now

Answer (score -1):

The root cause is that I have a double optional here. It could be unwrapped like this :

```
typealias ChessItemPosition = (alpha:Character, num:Int)
typealias Chessman = Dictionary<String,ChessItemPosition?>

var chessmans : Chessman = [:]
chessmans["White king"] = (alpha : "e", num : 2)
chessmans["Black king"] = (alpha : "e", num : 6)
chessmans["Black queen"] = nil

var itemPosition = chessmans["Black queen"]

if let chessItemPosition = itemPosition, let chessItemPosition_ = chessItemPosition {
    print("Current position is : \(chessItemPosition_.alpha)\(chessItemPosition_.num)")
} else {
    print("Black queen is dead")
}
```